# Como implementar VUEX desde CDN en vuejs CDN. Uncaught ReferenceError: createStore is not define at

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

No puedo usar VUEX 4 en vue 3 porque me tira el error

Uncaught ReferenceError: createStore is not defined
at Visita.js:2

Claramente es porque estoy usando mas la instancia de VUEX, pero no funciona y la documentacion me indic como hacerlo  segun https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/#the-simplest-store

el index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.6.2/dist/vuex.js"></script>
</head>

<body>



<div id="app"  class="d-flex justify-content-center flex-column">

      <aviso-visita />

  </div>

</body>

<script src="<?=base_url?>vue/src/view/AvisoVisita.js"></script> 
<script src="<?=base_url?>vue/src/store/Visita.js"></script>
<!-- componentes -->
<script src="<?=base_url?>vue/src/components/visita/Modal.js"></script>


 <script>

   app.mount('#app')

 </script>

</html>
```

view/Avisovisita.js

```
  const app = Vue.createApp({})
// app.mount('#app')

// btnJqAviso es desactivado con jquery al iniciar una transaccion

app.component('aviso-visita',{
    template : /*html*/  
    
    `
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button 
        id="btnJqAviso" 
        class="mx-2 c-Button-cyan"
        @click="openModal"
        >
        <span> {{ texto }} </span> <i class="fas fa-truck"></i> </button>
    </div>
        
    <modal-contacto :titleModal="titleModal"  v-if="myModel" />
      
    `,
    data (){
        return {
            texto: 'Aviso de visita',
            myModel : false,
            titleModal : 'Visita'
        }
    },
    methods : {
        mostrarBuscador(){
        this.buscadorFlag = true
        },
        openModal(){
            this.myModel = true
        }
    }
})
```

store/Visita.js

```
    const store = createStore({
       state () {
         return {
           count: 10
         }
       },
       mutations: {
         increment (state) {
           state.count++
         }
       }
     })
  
app.use(store);
```

Es la manera de hacerlo, claro, usando el import  from 'vuex'

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

// Create a new store instance.
const store = createStore({
  state () {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    increment (state) {
      state.count++
    }
  }
})

const app = createApp({ /* your root component */ })

// Install the store instance as a plugin
app.use(store)
```

Pero yo lo estoy implementando en un proyecto que ya esta iniciado con jquery,
por lo tanto tengo la posibilidad de trabajarlo solo con cdn. Pero obviamente estoy importando mal el vuex, he podido trabajar de manera fluida con vue js normal. El problema
viene al querer usar vuex. Busque mucha información , guias y no encontré de que manera
implemtarlo usando cdn. Si con cli, pero no con CDN. Estoy usando vuex 4 para la version de vue 3 como indica la documentación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Recientemente lidie con el problema descrito en su pregunta, ahora comparto una solución.

Answer (score 0):

## Vue 3 y Vuex 4 con cdn

Comparto ejemplo de código de un contador con Vue 3 y Vuex 4 usando CDN. Normalmente se usa Vue 3 y Vuex 4 con Vue CLI, pero para excepciones es posible que tengamos que usar el CDN y aquí cambia un poco la forma de usarlo. Lo que normalmente se hace con un `import`, con el CDN se hace de la siguiente manera:

```
const {createStore, mapState, mapMutations} = Vuex;
```

El ejemplo funcional a continuación:

```js
const {createApp} = Vue;
const {createStore, mapState, mapMutations} = Vuex;
// Create a Vue application
const app = createApp({});

app.component("contador",{
    template: `
    <div>
        <h2>Numero: {{ n }}</h2>
        <button @click="increment">+</button>
        <numero></numero>
    </div>
    `,
    computed:{
        ...mapState(['n'])
    },
    methods:{
        ...mapMutations(['increment']),
    }


})

app.component("numero",{
    template: `
    <div>
        <h2>Numero: {{ n }}</h2>
    </div>
    `,
    computed:{
        ...mapState(['n'])
    }

})

const store = createStore({
    state(){
            return{
                n: 0
                }
        },
    mutations: {
            increment (state) {
            state.n++
            }
          }
 })

app.use(store)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@4.0.2/dist/vuex.global.js"></script>

<div class="container" id="app">
     
       <contador/>

   </div>
```